# How to increase an output of opamp in this noise generator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, synthesizer

I'm working on a noise generator for my analog synthesizer and have problems with current design I built. As a noise source I use NPN-transistor in avalanche mode with only base and emitter connected. I tried different but stopped on BC548, which give 10mV peak to peak in current configuration. All signals in synth are normalized to [-2.5,2.5]V range, so I need to multiply this signal with a factor of 500. I tried to use a multistage transistor amplifier, built one stage with amp of 50 and dropped this idea. Now I sketched and build this circuit on a breadboard, with 1/2 of TL072 (don't have other on hand) but measuring it with my scope gives same amplitude on output as on input, only reduced in bandwidth. I tried to use a pot as R3, and rotating it left and right don't affect an output. Can you help me to trace a problem or advice better design for this circuit?

[image: Noise Amp Schematics]

Comment: Thanks for posting to EE.SE, sorry but your question needs improvement. It needs to be more specific (please re-read the rules). "I need help" is not a question, please edit your question and ask a question directly relating to your design, like "How do I increase the gain of the circuit?" or "How do I increase the bandwidth" to through out some examples. Thanks

Comment: @laptop2d thanks for notice. It was not clear for me what kind of problem I had in a circuit, so I asked a general question. I'll fix it

Answer (score 4):

You've basically killed off the noise source by using a value of R2 at 100 ohms. This acts as an impedance to ground (virtual earth) and leads to only the higher end of the spectrum coming through because of the really low value of C1 (47 pF). It forms a high pass filter with a 3dB point of nearly 34 MHz.

Even if you increased C1 to 47 uF (3 dB point of 34 Hz), the loading effect of R2 is too high. Try using a non-inverting op-amp configuration - it has a high input impedance and should work much better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Right. I missed it out. I'll try a non-inverting configuration today

Comment: Is a gain of 500 realistic, or would two stages be better?

Comment: @JRE if bandwidth required is 20 kHz and gain required is 500, GBW product of a single op-amp would need to be significantly bigger than 10 MHz. But given that a little bit of roll-off and inaccuracy in the 10 kHz+ region probably won't be a spoiler a 10 MHz op amp is probably acceptable.